# Refreshed Google API does not get file list form drive. Google_Service_Exception (Err 400)

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to connect my web application with Google Drive, using the Google Drive API V2 and Google's PHP client library (`"google/apiclient": "^2.0"`).

My application works fine for first hour. I can get files, uploads files, etc. but after 1 hour (when the access token expires and needs to be refreshed), subsequent gets/uploads result in a `Google_Service_Exception (Err 400)`:

> Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.

[image]

I successfully obtain access & refresh tokens:

```
{
 "access_token":"**********",
 "expires_in":3600,
 "refresh_token":"1/********",
 "scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
 "token_type":"Bearer",
 "created":1539085127
}
```

I have tried to refresh the token this way:

```
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
}
```

And this way:

```
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->refreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
}
```

How can I properly maintain the credentials I received for more than an hour?

Comment: A 400 error means you've not sent what they expect to receive

Comment: what library are you using?

Comment: php library @delboy1978uk
in codeigniter

Comment: that doesn't help, i need the package name or i cant look at their code#

Comment: {
    "require": {
        "google/apiclient": "^2.0"
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something is wrong with your client setup.  Try this

```
function getOauth2Client() {
    try {

        $client = buildClient();

        // Set the refresh token on the client. 
        if (isset($_SESSION['refresh_token']) && $_SESSION['refresh_token']) {
            $client->refreshToken($_SESSION['refresh_token']);
        }

        // If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
        // else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
        if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {

            // Set the access token on the client.
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);                 

            // Refresh the access token if it's expired.
            if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {              
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
                $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken()); 
                $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();              
            }           
            return $client; 
        } else {
            // We do not have access request access.
            header('Location: ' . filter_var( $client->getRedirectUri(), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Ripped from [Oauth2Authentication.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Drive%20API/v2/Oauth2Authentication.php) might help as well [oauth2callback.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Drive%20API/v2/oauth2callback.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get file list by using curl.

if you want to get all file from google drive.

**Use This Url in curl:**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files
```

Or, If you want to get file from specific folder.

**Use This Url in curl:**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q='".$yourDriveFolderId."'+in+parents
```

[Google Drive Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list)